Как отключить выделение пробельных символов VS Code
Как отключить выделение табов как на картинке (отмечено красным)


В настройках, Editor: Render Whitespace -> none.
Или оно же в settings.json:
"editor.renderWhitespace": "none",


Дополню.
То, что у вас это пробелы. Табы выглядат вот так:

В любом случае отображение можно регулировать через Command Palette. Наиболее быстрый способ для таких настроек

Нажмите F1
Начните вводить whitespaces
Выберите View: Toggle Render Whitespace

